# Save audio file in chunk from original file

Tags: php, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I actually want a demo version for audio file. I uploaded audio file in mp3 format on server with php script. I want that it run for 30 seconds in demo mode and for register user it play whole file.

There is a solution using ffmpeg library while uploading split file in frames and save one for demo and one for  original. But I need some different solution because ffmpeg not available on shared server.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Create a second upload field for the demo file.

Comment: No. I want it to be done by coding.

Comment: @M_Yasin, you are a masochist.  Get a host that has ffmpeg available.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cut an MP3 (reliably) on frames alone.  There is something called a bit reservoir, where basically frames can rely on other frames.  Most frames will be using this feature.  If you cut on the frame, you will undoubtedly end up with a corrupt file, and have a few artifacts in your clip.

To do what you are asking, you have two options:

1. Parse the MP3 data and cut only on frames not using the bit reservoir
2. Write an encoder that can cut on any frame and fix the bit reservoir so that prior and latter frames are not needed.

Neither of these are good options.  Call your web host, get FFMPEG installed.  If they won't put it on there for you, get a new hosting provider.  Don't waste your time with anything else.